# How to get Min Max as out put from single column grouped by user in select query

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I am not good in SQL raw queries. Please help to get Min Max value grouped by the user_id.

**Scenario is:**

Table has multiple values in column "B" against user_id and i want to out put the column "B" twice as Min/Max in single output. Required output will looks like:

```
User_id, MaxB, MinB
1        5     2
2        10    3
```

Consider the Table has 5 entries for both user(1, 2) but the out put prints it as a single row with max and min of B. Thanks in advance. Suggest the link if i am repeating this question as i was unable to find the solution.

Comment: You have already it, now use `GROUP BY`, `MAX` and `MIN`.

Comment: @jarlh, is this you want to say? Select Max(B), Min(B) from table group by Max, Min?

Comment: select User_id, max(col_with_val), min(col_with_val) from table group by User_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select Max(B) as MAXB, Min(B) as MinB, User_ID 
from TableName
group by User_ID
```

Comment: Let me try. Thanks for your prompt reply.

Comment: It worked! Thanks for the reply. i was messing with group by.